# Distribuir archivos en varios servidores

Tags: java, python

Tengo cierta cantidad de archivos en una ruta local y debo enviarlos a tres servidores, pero la cantidad debe estar divida en los tres servidores es decir si en la ruta local hay seis archivos en cada servidor deben ir dos y así sucesivamente, he pensado en varias cosas pero no me ocurre nada.

Si alguien me pudiera dar una idea les agradezco

Comment: Como esta planteada, la pregunta es basada en opiniones.. debe haber montones de formas de hacer esto, y mas en dos lenguajes totalmente distintos.. que intentaste hasta ahora? si no, la pregunta va a ser cerrada...

Comment: Bueno mas que una opinión es que sea una idea por que como le he pensado e intentado no me ha servido, intente con un For en ambos lenguajes y no me funciono(creo que como lo hice no es la forma), el tema de lenguaje lo deje abierto ya que conozco de esos dos y así poder adaptarlo a lo que necesito

Comment: una idea es una opinion... porque mejor no mostras que intentaste y trabajamos con eso?

Comment: Recorre la lista de archivos: Envia el archivo al servidor de destino, cambia al siguiente servidor de destinos. O sea, el servidor 1 recibe el archivo 1, 4, 7 ... El servidor 2 recibe 2, 5, 8 ... El servidor 3 recibe 3, 6, 9, No hay ni necesidad de contar o dividir.

Comment: Ok pero como lo debería hacer ? Por que se me ocurre en listar el directorio y que entre a un for pero no se como hacer para que lo envié al servidor que corresponde